# "Area of improvement" or "point of improvement" or synonyms

Tags: idioms, synonyms

I am looking for a good way or alternative ways of saying "points of/for improvements" in the meaning:

- Peter has many weaknesses (so he could improve in many areas). Could one then say "Peter has many options for improvement" ?
- A web application is not very user friendly. Could one then say "It has many areas for improvement" ?

Comment: I think the collocation is 'room for improvement'.

Comment: @Fantasier Thanks. Could you give some examples of usage?

Comment: I think it probably doesn't mean exactly what you wanted. See the [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/room-for-improvement). *There's room for improvement in the way the tickets are sold* (From LDOCE5). *There is still room for improvement in your work* (From the OALD8).

Comment: Actually I found *an area for/of improvement* in Oxford Collocations Dictionary with this example: *The new assessment system could pinpoint areas for improvement within the company.* This one probably suits better, I think.

Comment: "Area of improvement" is just fine. "Point of impovement" is not so good but the meaning is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Peter has a lot of room for improvement."

"The web app has a lot of room for improvement."

"Peter has much room for improvement" is correct, but less common, so will make you sound succinct and pithy if you're careful or (potentially) less fluent if you're not.

"Peter has many options for improvement" is valid, but it has a connotation that you might not expect. If you said that, it sounds like you could have also said "Peter has many options for *improving*," which seems to connote (facetiously, jokingly) that he's selecting one choice from a collection of possibilities, as if he were shopping or something, which, since it sounds facetious because it's uncommon, seems to say, "if he *chose* to improve, he could, but he doesn't." This interpretation would happen only very contextually though; it would mostly just sound unfluent.

Other related phrases include:
has room to grow,
something to work on,
a way to better (your)self, (grand connotation).

Hope it helps!